# Reagent input not updating

Tags: reactjs, clojurescript, reagent

I'm trying to build a Hello World app with Reagent/React. I tie an input with an atom using `:value`/`:on-change` combo. However, when I type, the input remains empty:

```
(defn new-user []
  ; Atom declared in an inner `let`.
  (let [v (atom "")]
    [:div
     [:input {:type "text"
              :value @v
              :on-change (fn [evt]
                           (reset! v (-> evt .-target .-value)))
              }]]))

(defn app [state]
  [:div
   [:p "State" (pr-str @app-state)]
   [new-user]])

(r/render-component [app app-state]
                    (.-body js/document))
```

If I move the atom out of `let`, it will work:

```
; Atom is now top-level.
(defonce v (atom ""))

(defn new-user []
  [:div
   [:input {:type "text"
            :value @v
            :on-change (fn [evt]
                         (reset! v (-> evt .-target .-value)))
            }]])
```

Is it because the `v` will be redeclared each time React re-renders? If so, how do I refactor that code so I don't have to use global variable to hold `v`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I turned out to be pretty easy - the "component" function can return not a template, but a function returning template. This way the outer function will be executed only once (and we can put `let` there), and inner will be executed on every re-render:

```
(defn new-user []
  (let [v (atom "")]
    ; The returned function will be called on every re-render.
    (fn []
      [:div
       [:input {:type "text"
                :value @v
                :on-change (fn [evt]
                             (reset! v (-> evt .-target .-value)))}]])))
```

Comment: This solution never worked for me until I changed `:value` to `:defaultValue`.